# Bitcoind sync status at ~block 206286

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu, server

I installed bitcoind on an ubunto server. If I execute bitcoind getinfo, I get the following output:

```
"relayfee":1.0E-5,"difficulty":3304356.39299034,"blocks":206286,"keypoolsize":101,"version":90201,"timeoffset":0,"balance":0.0,"errors":"","paytxfee":0.0,"proxy":"","testnet":false,"connections":38,"protocolversion":70002,"walletversion":60000
```

So it seems like it synced until block 206286. Around twelfe hours ago it 206154, so the number increased with normal block discovery time I would say. Connections are at 38 so this should be fine.

But if I checked correctly the actual current block is 300 000 something.

Does someone know whats the status of the wallet or how can I check it/

Comment: Two things to try: 1. Stop bitcoind and restart it.  2. Look at the debug.log file.

Comment: Quick question: did you install bitcoind using "apt-get install bitcoind" ?

Comment: restarting helped. But it got stuck over and over again. Starting it with just one thread made it more stable (bitcoind -par=1 &)